# The Borel Argument - 1 cm displacement of hydrogen atom on distant star effect on microstates on system on Earth

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I was wondering if anyone had the derivation to Borel's famous arguement that a displacement of 1 cm on a particle on a distant star would significantly affect the microstate configuration on a system on earths surface.

Either the full derivation or the link to the full derivation would be very much appreciated.

If you do not have a link to the exact derivation, the following system approximately satisfies Borel's original system.
- One mole of nitrogen gas at standard temperature and pressure (STP) at earths surface.
- a single hydrogen atom is displaced 1 cm on the closest star Proxima Centauri which is about 4 light years away. After the delay from the relativistic limits of signal propagation, estimate how long it would take for the microstates of the hydrogen gas to significantly differ from the differential gravitational effects  if the hydrogen atom was not displaced.